# How enable the indy OpenSSL hash functions on Android?

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-10-seattle

On a Firemonkey (Android) application I'm trying to use the *OpenSSL* hash functions through Indy, but the hash functions its seems not available.

the `IsHMACSHA512Avail`, `IsHMACSHA384Avail`, `IsHMACSHA384Avail`, `IsHMACSHA1Avail` functions always return *false*.

This is the code that I'm using

```
uses
 IdSSLOpenSSL,
 IdHashSHA,
 IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders,
 IdFIPS,
 IdHash;

function HashString(const AString : string): String;
var
  LSHA : TIdHashIntF;
begin
  Result := AString;

  if IsHMACSHA512Avail then //I tried with several hash classes 
  begin
    LSHA := TIdHashSHA512.Create; 
    try
      Exit(LSHA.HashStringAsHex(AString));
    finally
      LSHA.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

How I can enable the indy *OpenSSL* hash functions on Android?

Comment: That means either 1) your version of Indy has `OPENSSL_NO_SHA512` and `OPENSSL_NO_SHA` defined, so Indy will not try to load the relevant hash functions, or 2) the OpenSSL binaries on Android are not exporting the relevant hash functions.